# How to add a redirect from a controller

Tags: php, magento

I already tried every version of this script found here and there, but it's still not working.
I have a controller doing certain actions after saving an order in the back-end. One of this action is to produce automatically an invoice on certain conditions. Usual redirect sends me back to the order view: I'd like to go to the invoice view instead.

```
$url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('sales_order_invoice/view', array('invoice_id' => $invoice->getId(), 'order_id' => $order->getId()));
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
```

This code is not working: I'm redirected to the order view as usual. The observer is trigger on `sales_order_save_after`.
How can i redirect properly?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below which is working for me in custom module of admin controller..

```
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array('order_id'=>$order_num)));
        return;
```

hope this will work for you. let me know if i can assist you more.

Comment: Mage::app()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect(age::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array('order_id'=>$order_num)))
            ->sendResponse();
        exit(0);

Comment: `$this->getResponse()` is `null`. `exit(0)` made it, thank you Amit Bera. Anyway I found out that I was calling `$invoice->getId()` before the invoice is actually created.. I have to figure out how and when to create the correct url now!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the default controller redirect functions?

```
function someAction()

{
  /* do your thing*/
     $this->_redirect('*/sales_invoice/view',
                       array('invoice_id'=> $invoice->getId())
     );
}
```

One thing to keep in mind, is that _redirect (nor your method) will redirect until the action function is complete.  If this redirect is inside of an "if statement" you'll need to add a return; afterwords to exit any remaining functionality.